# what makes inactive questions active

Tags: support, bumping, questions, frontpage

What makes an inactive question to appear in active list? [The question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1392247/how-do-ideal-quotients-behave-with-respect-to-localization) asked in 2015/8/10 and has 2 answers (one accepted). There is no recent comment, answer, edition, and other activities.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, there was an answer posted earlier today, and shortly after deleted by the author. For users below 10k reputation, such activities are invisible, but users with [at least 10k](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) can see it.

Generally, sometimes inactive questions are bumped by the community bot, which also can bring actually inactive questions to the front page or the "active" tab.

Comment: Thanksssssssssssss